# How to map variables using nested dictionaries in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

So I couldn't really find anything that could help me with what i'm trying to do by searching in the previous posts. I'm also relatively new at python.

Essentially, what i'm trying to do is figure out the most streamlined way to create multiple variables from one single variable.

Lets say my data looks like this

```
CaseNumber   Offense
ABC123       1      
ABC123       1
ABC124       24
ABC124       62
ABC125       12
ABC126       10
```

what i'm wondering how to do is if i can use a nested dictionary to create variables like so:

```
offense_variable = { 'Traffic', {1:1},
'Violence', {24:1},
'DUI', {62:1},
'Theft', {12:1},
'Drugs', {10:1}
}
```

and use the map function to create the variable values for "Traffic," "Violence," etc from the keys in offense.

Thank you!

EDIT:

```
The goal is essentially to turn this: 

CaseNumber   Offense
ABC123       1      
ABC123       1
ABC124       24
ABC124       62
ABC125       12
ABC126       10
```

into this:

```
CaseNumber   Offense   Traffic   Violence    DUI    Theft    Drugs   Flag    
ABC123       1           1         0          0       0       0        1
ABC123       1           1         0          0       0       0        1
ABC124       24          0         1          0       0       0        1 
ABC124       62          0         0          1       0       0        1
ABC125       12          0         0          0       1       0        0
ABC126       10          0         0          0       0       1        1
```

and also some added functionality that incorporates other dummy flags flags. for instance, let's say if the last column, "flag," is 1, then theft would also be 1, in addition to offense = 12.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised response, based on the OP's comment below.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''CaseNumber   Offense
ABC123       1      
ABC123       1
ABC124       24
ABC124       62
ABC125       12
ABC126       10
'''
# create data frame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python')

# create dict of dict
offense_variable = { 'Traffic': {1: 1}, 'Violence': {24: 1},
    'DUI': {62: 1}, 'Theft': {12: 1}, 'Drugs': {10: 1} }

# flatten the offense_variable from nested dicts to ordinary dict
ov = { num: desc
      for desc, vs in offense_variable.items()
      for num, _ in vs.items() }

# use flattened dict to convert Offense (number) to desc (string)
df['offense_desc'] = df['Offense'].map(ov)

# use `.get_dummies()` for one-hot encoding
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['offense_desc'])], axis=1)

print(df)

  CaseNumber  Offense offense_desc  DUI  Drugs  Theft  Traffic  Violence
0     ABC123        1      Traffic    0      0      0        1         0
1     ABC123        1      Traffic    0      0      0        1         0
2     ABC124       24     Violence    0      0      0        0         1
3     ABC124       62          DUI    1      0      0        0         0
4     ABC125       12        Theft    0      0      1        0         0
5     ABC126       10        Drugs    0      1      0        0         0
```

Comment: The goal is to create traffic, violence, dui, theft, and drugs as new columns (they'll be dummies, essentially 1/0's) in my dataframe based upon the offense's values. if this works correctly, how would i call the inverted map to create the new columns? sorry, i'm super new at this :(

Comment: Please can you update the question to include the expected output?

Comment: I revised the response, to create a column for each offense (DUI, Drugs, etc.).  Does Flag mean that CaseNumber has multiple offenses?

Comment: so in the real data (this is fake because of data-sharing agreements), the offenses will actually be written descriptions of the offense. sometimes the offense might contain information that can be used to create more than one variable. lets say the offense is "assault with a motor vehicle." that would be coded as a violent offense, but also "flagged" for traffic. so in this case, traffic and violence would both be "1's."